# ¿Como mantener el incremento de un carrito de compra con localStorage? jquery

Tags: jquery, local-storage

estoy haciendo un carrito de compras pero primero quiero que al presionar comprar el contador se quede con el mismo valor al pasar a otras paginas, eso funciona el problema es que cuando vuelvo al index y vuelvo a presionar comprar se reinicia el contador de nuevo y quisiera q eso no pase:

(tambien intente poner el localStorage.setItem afuera de la function click pero asi solo me funciona el contador en el index entonces ya no se como hacer q funcione)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  let contador = 0;

  $(".comprar").click(function() {


    contador++;

    $(".contador").text(contador);

    localStorage.setItem("contadorCarrito", contador);

  })

  const contadorCarritoLS = localStorage.getItem("contadorCarrito");

  $(".contador").text(contadorCarritoLS);
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background: #000;
}

.agregar {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav {
  background: #000;
  padding: 5px;
}

.carrito {
  margin-left: 558px;
}

.carrito,
.contador {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}

.productos {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: #000;
  margin-top: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.productos>div {
  background: #78288C;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 200px;
  color: #fff;
}

input {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pages.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/carrito.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="page1.html">PAGE1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.html">PAGE2</a></li>
        <li><a href="page3.html">PAGE3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="carrito">carrito
      <p class="contador">0
        <p>
    </div>
  </header>
  <br><br>
  <section class="productos">

    <div>
      <p class="precio1">100</p>
      <input type="submit" value="comprar" class="comprar">
    </div>

    <div>
      <p class="precio2">300</p>
      <input type="submit" value="comprar" class="comprar">
    </div>

    <div>
      <p class="precio3">500</p>
      <input type="submit" value="comprar" class="comprar">
    </div>

    <div>
      <p class="precio4">800</p>
      <input type="submit" value="comprar" class="comprar">
    </div>

  </section>


</body>

</html>
<!--page2--->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/carrito.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pages.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="page1.html">PAGE1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.html">PAGE2</a></li>
        <li><a href="page3.html">PAGE3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="carrito">carrito
      <p class="contador">0
        <p>
    </div>
  </header>

  <h2>otra pagina</h2>

</body>

</html>
<!----page3--->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/carrito.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pages.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="page1.html">PAGE1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.html">PAGE2</a></li>
        <li><a href="page3.html">PAGE3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="carrito">carrito
      <p class="contador">0
        <p>
    </div>
  </header>

  <h2>otra pagina</h2>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es lógico que eso ocurra, porque estás inicializando a `0`  el valor cada vez que se entra en la página.

Podrías resolverlo con algo como esto:

```
//document.ready  es obsoleto, usa function
$(function() {
  //Si no existe, tomará el valor 0
  let contador = localStorage.getItem("contadorCarrito") || 0;
  $(".comprar").click(function() {
    $(".contador").text(contador);
    //Aumentamos y seteamos directamente, es mejor así
    localStorage.setItem("contadorCarrito", contador++);
  });
  //Aquí igualmente, puedes tomar el valor directamente
  $(".contador").text(localStorage.getItem("contadorCarrito"));
});
```

Así debería funcionar, salvo otros errores. Por ejemplo, los ámbitos de las funciones son incorrectos en el código de tu pregunta.